# How to Disable Auto-Formatting of All Column Values when opening CSV Files in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, csv, text-formatting

How can I stop Microsoft Excel from auto formatting data when imported from a csv/text file? Specifically, I want it to treat all of the values as text.

The files come to me as tab delimited text files. When loaded/opened in Excel, Excel auto-formats the data causing leading 0's on values to be truncated and often converting the values into dates.

We do not want to click through the import wizard an specify that each column is text. We would rather open the .csv file and have it be handled accordingly.

Ideally I just want to turn off Excel's Auto-Formatting completely, and just edit every cell as it were plain text. There are no formulas to be concerned with.

This is NOT an Auto Correct or "Replace text as you type" problem so it doesn't appear to be addressable by the AutoCorrect panel.

Comment: This may be best solved with a little vba script that and a QuickAccess Toolbar button.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Import Text File Wizard](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/806-excel-import-text-worksheet-file.html#a1), you can choose data type for each column.

Comment: I agree that this avoids the problem, but OP explicitly asked for some way to automate this process... "We do not want to click through the import wizard an specify that each column is text. "